# "QueryPerf" method of vSphere API returns strange results

Tags: php, soap, vsphere, esxi

I need to get average daily statistics for given VM.
VM runs on VMware vSphere 5.1. I use PHP and call methods through SOAP.

My code looks like this:

```
$result = $this
        ->soapClient
        ->QueryPerf( array(
            '_this' => $this->serviceContent->perfManager,
            'querySpec' => array(
                'entity'        => $object,
                'startTime'     => $startTime->format( 'c' ),
                'intervalId'    => 86400,
            ),
        ) );
```

Returned results for CPU usage as a percentage during the interval and memory usage as percentage of total configured or available memory look very strange.

CPU result:

```
  stdClass::__set_state(array(
     'groupInfo' => 
    stdClass::__set_state(array(
       'label' => 'CPU',
       'summary' => 'CPU',
       'key' => 'cpu',
    )),
     'nameInfo' => 
    stdClass::__set_state(array(
       'label' => 'Usage',
       'summary' => 'CPU usage as a percentage during the interval',
       'key' => 'usage',
    )),
     'rollupType' => 'average',
     'statsType' => 'rate',
     'unitInfo' => 
    stdClass::__set_state(array(
       'label' => 'Percent',
       'summary' => 'Percentage',
       'key' => 'percent',
    )),
     'instance' => '',
     'value' => 349,
  )),
```

The unit is **percent** but the value is **349**.

Memory result:

```
  stdClass::__set_state(array(
     'groupInfo' => 
    stdClass::__set_state(array(
       'label' => 'Memory',
       'summary' => 'Memory',
       'key' => 'mem',
    )),
     'nameInfo' => 
    stdClass::__set_state(array(
       'label' => 'Usage',
       'summary' => 'Memory usage as percentage of total configured or available memory',
       'key' => 'usage',
    )),
     'rollupType' => 'average',
     'statsType' => 'absolute',
     'unitInfo' => 
    stdClass::__set_state(array(
       'label' => 'Percent',
       'summary' => 'Percentage',
       'key' => 'percent',
    )),
     'instance' => '',
     'value' => 1193,
  )),
```

The unit is also **percent** but the value is **1193**.

The other values have the same issues.

**Questions:**
What am I doing wrong?
How to get valid results?

**Note:** these results are slightly postformatted, but no calculations or other modifications of values are performed on the client side.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[look at the docs](https://pubs.vmware.com/vsphere-51/index.jsp#com.vmware.wssdk.apiref.doc/vim.PerformanceManager.CounterInfo.Unit.html). You should divide percent value by 100, to get real percent value.